# Vertical spacing between \framebox-ed elements of list

Tags: itemize, enumitem, framed

I'm new to this stuff, but I am trying to create an alphabetical list where the elements are in one column with a box around it and a line between each element (I want to be able to print it and cut them apart easily). I can get the boxes close to each other, but I can't seem to get them to overlap (so that there is one line between each element instead of the edges of two boxes). Thanks for any help!!

Here is what I've got:

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in, footskip=30pt}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\usepackage{datatool}
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{
  \DTLnewrow{list}
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}
}{
  \DTLsort{description}{list}
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0em,itemsep=0em,partopsep=0em,parsep=0em]
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{
      \item \theDesc}
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in\width]{The last list item\strut}}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in\width]{Here's another list item\strut}}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in\width]{A list item\strut}}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `sortedlist` environment definition, I changed `itemsep` to `-1.5pt`.

Also, I eliminated the faulty syntax of `\width` from your `\framebox`es.

```
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper, margin=1in, footskip=30pt}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{nosep}

\usepackage{datatool}
\newcommand{\sortitem}[1]{
  \DTLnewrow{list}
  \DTLnewdbentry{list}{description}{#1}
}
\newenvironment{sortedlist}{
  \DTLifdbexists{list}{\DTLcleardb{list}}{\DTLnewdb{list}}
}{
  \DTLsort{description}{list}
  \begin{itemize}[topsep=0em,itemsep=-1.5pt,partopsep=0em,parsep=0em]
    \DTLforeach*{list}{\theDesc=description}{
      \item \theDesc}
  \end{itemize}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sortedlist}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in]{The last list item\strut}}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in]{Here's another list item\strut}}
  \sortitem{\framebox[1.5in]{A list item\strut}}
\end{sortedlist}

\end{document}
```

[image]